# Как сменить текущий системный язык Android устройства программно?

Tags: android, locale

Как сменить язык приложения через один из вариантов ниже я знаю:

```
this.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().setTo(configuration);
```

Но всё это влияет только на активность или приложение, но не на всю систему.
Мне нужно сменить локаль так, как это делает, к примеру, приложение MoreLocale способное установить даже такой язык, которого нет с списке языков в настройках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покопавшись, я нашёл два способа.

1. Командами adb: `{"setprop persist.sys.language ru", "setprop persist.sys.country RU" "stop", "start"};`
   Но этот способ мне не понравился - происходит быстрая перезагрузка, которая на моём одноядерном проце растягивается на полминуты с показом логотипа Android.
2. Способы описанные [здесь](http://bin-liu.blogspot.ru/2012/05/how-to-change-system-locale-calling.html). Я взял способ с рефлексией. Работает хорошо, мгновенно, но только если перед этим послать в adb `pm grant com.yourapp android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`. Вот он:

   ```
   try {
           Class<?> activityManagerNative = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
           Object am = activityManagerNative.getMethod("getDefault").invoke(activityManagerNative);
           Object config = am.getClass().getMethod("getConfiguration").invoke(am);
           config.getClass().getDeclaredField("locale").set(config, Locale.US);
           config.getClass().getDeclaredField("userSetLocale").setBoolean(config, true);
           am.getClass().getMethod("updateConfiguration", android.content.res.Configuration.class).invoke(am, config);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

По нормальному никак. Нет никаких публичных API, которые позволяют это (программно изменить системный язык всего устройства) сделать, что в общем то неудивительно, поскольку противоречит общей концепции оси.

Но есть разные хаки, [описаны здесь](http://bin-liu.blogspot.ru/2012/05/how-to-change-system-locale-calling.html)

Не уверен, что они сейчас работают, скорее всего дырки залатали. Например, тот же [MoreLocale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale) - без рута или без шаманских подтанцовок уже по моему не работает.

Comment: Root не проблема в моём случае. Я б ещё мирился с обычным способом, но при смене языка предыдущая активность (главная) и тулбар остаются на прошлом языке сколько ни меняй. Плюс добавляется потребность запоминать настройки локали в преференсах и каждый раз их воспроизводить.